# C# MS Access database - sending second UPDATE command display error

Tags: c#, ms-access

Im trying to create UPDATE command to my program based on C# and Access database. And its working how i want it, but VS2013 display error when i try to update another or the same record second time.

> **InvalidComObjectException was unhandled.**
>   COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW can not be
>   used.

This is how my program looks like:

**FormA** - Main windows with DataGridView1 of table "Grafik" and Button to open **FormB**

**FormB** - Second form with DataGridView2 of table Employyes and Button to **FormC**

**FormC** - Form to add, delete and update records directly in to the database "Kategorie" using TextBox'es, ComboBox'es and Buttons (no directly on DataGridView)

UPDATE procedure uses ComboBox (**comboBoxWybierzKategorie**) to select "category" from database "Kategorie" to update, textBox (**textBoxEdytujKategorie**) to set new name of selected "Kategoria" and Button to accept procedure.

**Broker.cs**

```
        public void Update_Kategorie(Kategorie oldKategoria, Kategorie newKategoria)
    {
        try
        {

            command.CommandText = "UPDATE Kategorie SET Kategoria = @kat WHERE IDKategorii= @old";
            //command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kat", newKategoria.Kategoria);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@old", oldKategoria.IDKategorii);
            connection.Open();
            //command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int cmd = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //connection.Close();
            if (cmd > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Kategoria zaktualizowana pomyślnie");
                //connection.Close();


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wystąpił błąd podczas aktualizacji kategorii.",
                    "Dodawanie kategorii",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            }

        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
```

**FormC.cs**

```
private void buttonEdytujKategorie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Kategorie oldKategoria = new Kategorie();
        Kategorie newKategoria = new Kategorie();
        oldKategoria = comboBoxWybierzKategorie.SelectedItem as Kategorie;
        newKategoria.Kategoria = Convert.ToString(textBoxEdytujKategorie.Text);
        b.Update_Kategorie(oldKategoria, newKategoria);

        comboBoxWybierzKategorie.DataSource = b.FillComboBox_Kategorie(); //wypełnij comboBoxWybierzKategorie
        textBoxEdytujKategorie.Text = String.Empty; //wyczyść textBoxEdytujKategorie
        //this.Close();
        //this.Controls.Clear();
        //this.InitializeComponent();
```

I know that code is messed up, sorry for that. More interesting is when i close FormC and reopen it using Button, update function working fine, unless i want use it again.

VS2013 selecting this line as a reason of error:

```
int cmd = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Connection to database:

```
OleDbConnection connection;
    OleDbCommand command;

private void ConnectTo()
    {
        //inside//connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=bc3e-ps.accdb");
        /*outside*/
        connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\bc3e-ps.accdb");
        command = connection.CreateCommand();
```

What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding parameters to the command every time, you should not re-use the command object again.

Just call `connection.CreateCommand()` every time you want to execute another command.

You can re-use commands, but then you only want to set the existing parameters on each call instead of adding parameters on each call.